# POSTing to Google Web Application in Java

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

I have implemented a REST Api on google app engine using the google web application for java.

Currently my POST request to add a new member of staff to the database accepts its parameters in the url.

How can I change it so it checks if it receives the params in the url or as a json object and then does the insertion?

Here is the current working code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
    try {
        String forename = request.getParameter("forename");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        String phoneNum = request.getParameter("phoneNum");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        StaffDAO staffDAO = new StaffDAO();


        staff = staffDAO.insertStaff(new StaffInfo(1L, forename, surname, location, phoneNum, email));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have tried sending a test json object to the api through postman but it did not add the "staff member" to the database.

Comment: Take a look at cloud endpoints (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) which handles all the JSON deserialization for you. Otherwise you may want to consider jersey, rest-easy, etc.. If you really want to do it by hand and in a servlet you need a JSON deserializer (i recommend jackson) and use it to deserialize `request.getInputStream()` in your servlet. That is beginner stuff so you should find some good tutorials for that on the net.

Comment: Is there a way of checking whether the request has its params in the url or as json? @konqi

Comment: Uhm yes and no. You can analyze the content-type header, which should be set to `application/json` when you post a json body. But even if that is true you can still send the parameters as GET-Params at the same time. Since GET-Request must not contain a body you can implement both `doPost` and `doGet` and determine what to do like that.